# Why got null from getResult

Tags: java, android

I want to get the result of getServerResult() method but return "null". However, the Logcat inside the httpURLConnectionPost() method is normal which return "sucessful". Please answer me! why I got null outside the httpURLConnectionPost() method with getServerResult() method in this case?

```
private String serverResult;

public void httpURLConnectionPost(final String urlString){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.connect();

                String body = stringBuilder();

                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(body);
                writer.close();

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                    String line;
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));               

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilderResult.append(line);
                    }
                    String result = stringBuilderResult.toString();
                    Log.d("MSG","result= "+result);
                    setServerResult(result);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void setServerResult(String serverResult){
    this.serverResult = serverResult;
}

public String getServerResult(){
    return serverResult;
}
```

D/MSG: result = successful

using getServerResult() :
D/TAG: result = null

Comment: You are likely calling `getServerResult` before your `httpURLConnectionPost` has finished. You need to either set this up in an AsyncTask or your own listener interface to return the result when it's finished.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you calling httpURLConnectionPost? Regardless you should be using an async task for this, functions that call HTTP requests are not going to return anything because the code is executing and finishing before the response is received.
You need to make sure the task is complete before trying to get any data. Usually you would use an async task and in the onPostExecute portion you would do something to let the app know that data is returned.